# flutter mailto and url_launcher to not work

Tags: flutter, dart, email, url, mailto

I want to use email
and I use these two packages:

```
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  mailto: ^2.0.0
```

and I use this code :

```
launchMailto() async {
  final mailtoLink = Mailto(
    to: ['to@example.com'],
    cc: ['cc1@example.com', 'cc2@example.com'],
    subject: 'mailto example subject',
    body: 'mailto example body',
  );
  await launch('$mailtoLink');
}
```

but it not work

can anyone help me please how can I use mailto in my project?

and by the way when I change my android manifest, my grade can't run and my project destroy

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
sendMail() async {
  const url = 'mailto:youremailid.com';
  launchUrl(
    Uri.parse(url),
  ),
}
```

Your Widget:

```
ElevatedButton (
   child: Text(
    ' Send Mail',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
  ),
  onPressed: sendMail,
),
```

Comment: the function `launch` is now deprecated and even using the current available version (`launchUrl`), this code block does not work at all. I'm trying to invoke it and I'm receiving a unknown exception

Comment: @ebragaparah I have update my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you must configure your manifest and infoplis files.

You should have something like that:

AndroidManifest.xml - pay attention to the fact that each scheme must be declared inside one intent, not in the same as the others

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="YOUR_PACKAGE">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    
    <application
      /// Your application
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```